# WP API : date_query parameter

Tags: api, rest-api, wp-api

I'm using Wordpress API just to perform some tests. I'm currently working with the date_query parameter, which, in my case, doesn't work as expected.

Just consider this request : https://wptest.enguerranweiss.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[orderBy]=date&filter[order]=DESC&filter[date_query][after]=2016-10-13T17 (dummy install, dummy content)

What I expect : the API should only return the posts more recent than `2016-10-13`. Right now, the filter seems to be ignored.

Any idea?

Comment: Which version of WordPress are you using?

Comment: WP version 4.7.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of WP >= 4.7 `filter[]` is not supported and have been removed. Also WP REST API Plugin became part of WordPress Core.

According [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#list-posts) your link should be:

https://wptest.enguerranweiss.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?orderby=date&order=desc&after=2016-10-13T17:00:00

**EDIT**

As enguerranws mentioned the date should be in ISO8601 format

Comment: Damned, I've searched for this doc for hours. Thanks, just to complete your answer : the after param should be an ISO8601 date string (or WP returns an error).